# CSS Menu wrapping

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a CSS-based menu. I want it to be able to adjust when the browser resizes so I'm using floats to wrap the menu items to the next line as needed. However, I want to have an extra buffer cell at the end to round out the menu appearance, see the sample image below (this an image the designer made from photoshop).

[image: Example here]

I can set the background image of the containing div to fake it (using the clearing floats trick I found at http://quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html), but then I have the additional problem of having extra space on the right side because I the cited trick says I should set the width to 100% on the container. (see image below)

[image]

I also don't have any borders on that extra area after the last item. So, what's the proper way to go about this? Can anyone suggest any good online implementations I can check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give the container a `padding-right` and have that keep the menu items away from the right edge.

Comment: I dont know what the distance from the right edge will be ahead of time; it may change depending on browser window size

Comment: You can set the padding-right as a percentage. Does that help?